# Как проверить изменение какого-либо объекта в коллекции?

Tags: php

Есть большая выборка объектов, которая составляет коллекцию. Я хочу проверить, есть ли хоть в одном элементе коллекции (объекте) изменение. Как это **правильно** сделать?

Пример коллекции:

```
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "item1",
      deleted_at: null,
      created_at: "2018-07-03 09:10:53"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "item2",
      deleted_at: null,
      created_at: "2018-07-03 09:10:53"
    },

    ...
  ]
```

Хорошим ли вариантом будет использование `md5()`?

Comment: Это зависит от данных этих объектов, да и вообще вопрос слишком общий. Что за объекты, какая их структура, где хранятся?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov при чём тут структура? Это не претензия, а уточнение. С чего вы взяли что это слишком общий вопрос? Структуру сейчас покажу. Тянутся из БД, но какое это имеет отношение?

Comment: Но вопрос и в правду слишком общий. Как один из вариантов, это в объекте использовать магический метод `__set()` и проверять изменения. Записывать факт изменения флага в классе. У такого подхода есть недостаток. Например, цепочка `$object->date->setTime(...)` не приведёт к изменению флага. Только через явное присваивание

Comment: Если вы используете мягкое удаление (deleted_at: null) и created_at, то почему бы не использовать updated_at: null? Удобно и эффективно в сравнении

Comment: @Slava конечно я использую. Пробегаться по коллекции не хочу. Мне уже подсказали, что можно сделать событие на изменение, создании или удалении и записывать в другую таблицу тот же `md5` по дате и потом сверять. Есть ещё варианты. Если получится что-то реализовать - сделаю ответ.